# One of the string arrays is not sorted

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

```
import numpy as np

arr1=np.array(['102.0','135.0','135.0','152.0','93.0','95.0'])

print(arr1)
arr1.sort()
print(arr1)

print()

arr2=np.array(['86.0','82.0','84.0','87.0','95.0','89.0'])

print(arr2)
arr2.sort()
print(arr2)
```

The first array is not sorted, but second is sorted, why?. I cannot find the mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sort` function only sorts integers correctly, so for strings it sorts by the first character so the ones over a hundred will be before the one that are ninety something, the way to fix would be to change them to integers:

```
import numpy as np

arr1=np.array(['102.0','135.0','135.0','152.0','93.0','95.0'])
arr1 = arr1.astype(float)
print(arr1)
arr1.sort()
print(arr1)

print()

arr2=np.array(['86.0','82.0','84.0','87.0','95.0','89.0'])
arr2 = arr2.astype(float)
print(arr2)
arr2.sort()
print(arr2)
```

As @juanpa.arrivillaga mentioned:

> it sorts *lexicographically* by all the characters

Comment: "it sorts by the first character" it sorts *lexicographically* by all the characters

Answer (score 1):

You are sorting strings the sort function is properly sorting the string elements (e.g. "102.0" comes before "93.0"). If you want to sort integers properly, remove the double-quotes around all your elements:

```
arr1=np.array([102.0,135.0,135.0,152.0,93.0,95.0])
arr2=np.array([86.0,82.0,84.0,87.0,95.0,89.0])
```

Comment: In general, assume data people give As input is an example.. so instead of focusing to solve the example assume the data given is not originally being created in runtime like the example and is something given to the user as input from other resource. Yougkt my vote because your explanation touched the issue. Good luck!